# how to customize ModelForm filled data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this model:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
```

With this form:

```
class GalleryForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Gallery
```

And this view:

```
gform = GalleryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=galleryInstance)
```

In template a filled form is shown. For the `HeadImage` field it shows a link to an image related to the `HeadImage` field, and a fileinput with a `change` label:

```
{{ gform.HeadImage }}
```

Now instead of a link to the picture, I want to put the image into an `img` tag. I do this in the template as follows:

```
<img src={{ gform.HeadImage.value }}/>
```

What should I do so that the link doesn't show in the form?

Comment: try setting editable=False for the HeadImage field in your model

Comment: editable=false doesn't work,Note,this is an edit form!

Answer (score 2):

To prevent it from showing, use any of these three options:

1. Set `editable=False` on the model field;
2. Use the `fields` attribute of the `ModelForm`'s inner `Meta` class.
3. Use the `exclude` attribute of the `ModelForm`'s inner `Meta` class.

Which one to use depends on how often you want the field to show (never, or in select cases). See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) for more information on this.

Comment: editable=false doesn't work,for other 2 solutions I didn't find any way in your suggested documentation.

Comment: Specifying e.g. `exclude`: `model = Gallery; exclude = ('Head_Image',)` should prevent the form entry for that field to show up when you use the form. But, I get the feeling I'm misunderstanding the question: could you elaborate on _"What should I do so that the link doesn't show in the form?"_ What do you mean precisely with this?

Comment: I mean when gallery filled form is shown in my page,it automatically show current value of headImage as a link,and show an inputfile to change current value,I don't wanna it shows this link.remember I use this to show HeadImage in my template : {{ gallery_form.HeadImage }}

Comment: Perhaps you should then create a form yourself instead of using a `ModelForm`: `class GalleryForm(forms.Form): HeadImage = forms.ClearableFileInput()`. Supply some intial values, and construct the form manually in the template. In the view you then have to deconstruct it and update your models, but if Django's standard form generators don't work this might be your only option.

Comment: I can solve problem with writing manual code in template,but the main problem is that I have an Image_set related to a model named Images that automatically add new inputfiles to fill,I can't make it manual.how can I do this for a formset that have a set of Images?

Comment: It is a bit hard tot help since he solution is quite a large thing, but you could just add multiple inputs using Javascript on he fly.